# Haskell / Stack / Nix build fails, requiring pkg-config >= 0.9.0 and cairo >= 1.2.0, but latest versions are pkg-config 0.29.2 and cairo 1.15.4

Tags: haskell, cairo, haskell-stack, nix, nixpkgs

I'm building a Haskell project using Stack and Nix and depending on the `cairo` library from Hackage.

When I build the project, I get an error: unable to find `pkg-config >= 0.9.0` or `cairo >= 1.2.0`. However, the latest versions according to their websites are `pkg-config 0.29.2` and `cairo-1.15.4`, and this is reflected in the Nix package manager as well.

On the other hand, there's 
[this article from 2006 announcing the release of Cairo 1.2.0](https://www.cairographics.org/news/cairo-1.2.0/), which further confuses the issue.

### Questions

> 1. Why are the expected versions so wildly different from the published versions on `nixpkgs` and the `pkg-config` / `cairo` websites?
> 2. What advice do you have to get `cairo` to build on macOS (best case scenario: using Nix for system packages and Stack for Haskell packages)

Steps to reproduce:

```
> stack new cairo-test simple && cd cairo-test

# Now, to get Cairo
> stack install cairo

cairo-0.13.3.1: configure ...
Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
Configuring cairo-0.13.3.1...
setup: The program 'pkg-config' version >=0.9.0 is required but it could not be found.

# This version doesn't seem to exist (not on the pkg-config website, either).
> nix-env -qaP pkg-config
nixpkgs.pkgconfig          pkg-config-0.29.2
nixpkgs.pkgconfigUpstream  pkg-config-0.29.2

# However, if installed, a new error:
> nix-env -i pkg-config
installing ‘pkg-config-0.29.2’
building path(s) ‘/nix/store/m4ks2si7b78757c1rc43r0833pxkvjb3-user-environment’
created 102 symlinks in user environment
> stack install cairo
setup: The pkg-config package 'cairo' version >=1.2.0 is required but 
it could not be found.

# Again, this version doesn't seem to exist, either on the site on in `nixpkgs`
> nix-env -qaP cairo
nixpkgs.cairo  cairo-1.14.8

# Installing it anyway, to see what the next error is
> nix-env -i cairo
installing ‘cairo-1.14.8’
building path(s) ‘/nix/store/dcx0in96wcd7yd8q71y93jd5306vag8g-user-environment’
created 112 symlinks in user environment

# Get the same version error now that Cairo is installed
setup: The pkg-config package 'cairo' version >=1.2.0 is required but it could not be found.
```

Comment: I am far from being an expert in Haskell development with Nix but generally to use library packages with Nix, you must open a nix-shell: `nix-shell -p pkg-config cairo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By installing Homebrew and then cairo with `brew install cairo`, I was able to build the project.

However, this installed Cairo version 1.14 — the same that Nix installed! When I inspect  with `brew info cairo`, I see some more information:

```
cairo: stable 1.14.8 (bottled), devel 1.15.4, HEAD

==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✘
Required: freetype ✔, fontconfig ✔, libpng ✔, pixman ✔, glib ✔
```

I tried installing these dependencies with Nix, and uninstalling Homebrew. No luck -- got a ton of linking errors. And so I re-installed Homebrew and it works again.

This isn't the nice, clean solution I was looking for (had to install an external package manager), but it does solve the problem for now.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is not the library version, `1.14.8` is greater than `1.2.0`. The problem is that the cairo development files don't get linked into your environment, that is, `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH` is not set.

Three solutions:

1. Find the cairo-dev directory in `/nix/store`, and add it to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`. E.g.,

   ```
    $ cairodev=$(nix-store --query --outputs $(nix-instantiate '<nixpkgs>' -A cairo) | grep dev$)
    $ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$cairodev:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
   ```
2. Run stack from within a nix shell, `nix-shell -p pkgconfig cairo`.
3. Use stack's nix support, by adding the following to `stack.yml`:

   ```
   nix:
     enable: true
     packages: [pkgconfig, cairo]
   ```